# Most of the SE sites are down

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

Most of the SE sites are down for few mins, but MSE is working fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This includes https://stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: We're aware of the issue and yanking the affected web servers right now

Comment: Everything is working for me.

Comment: Confirmed occurrence; came back before I could post my own question here...

Comment: Everything is fine now. Situation normal. How are you?

Comment: As always dupe in MSO https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366555/stackoverflow-is-down

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, but not only SO, most of the SE sites.

Comment: There's an additional issue, almost as severe as the outage itself. **404** is a *client* error, not a *server* error.

Answer (score 3):

The same question has been asked in MSO, and an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366563/5437487) was given:

> We are in the process of upgrading our web servers. During the rebuild of a server it went back into rotation before we were ready for it to go back. This resulted in the "Default Web Site" that comes with an IIS install to appear. HAProxy regarded the page as a valid response and put it back in rotation.